# Is every 32-bit floating-point number is exactly representable with 64-bit floating number

Tags: floating-point, ieee-754, floating-accuracy

Is it possible to lose precision by converting 32-bit floating-point number to 64-bit floating number and converting it back again.

Does at least one such single 32-bit floating point number exist? (including subnormal numbers)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The set of values representable by IEEE-754 basic 32-bit binary floating-point is a subset of the values representable by IEEE-754 basic 64-bit binary floating-point. Any properly implemented conversion from this 32-bit floating-point to this 64-bit floating-point will not alter numeric values. Similarly, if a 64-bit floating-point number contains one of the values representable in the 32-bit format, any properly implemented conversion from this 64-bit format to the 32-bit format will not alter the numeric value.

NaNs carry payload information, and the conversion of payloads from one format to another is not fully specified by IEEE 754.

Some floating-point implementations “flush” subnormal values, meaning they replace them with zero. This behavior does not conform to IEEE 754 but is implemented by some hardware for performance or cost reasons. So an instruction that converts a 32-bit floating-point value to a 64-bit floating-point value but first flushes a subnormal value to zero would return an incorrect result. But of course the subnormal value would be flushed to zero in any arithmetic instruction anyway, so there is no net effect from flushing it to zero in a round-trip conversion.